# Assigning string[] array into a function with params string[]

Tags: c#, string, parameters

I have a function `void Test(int id, params string[] strs)`.

How would I pass an array of strings as the `strs` argument? When I call:

```
Test(1, "a, b, c");
```

It takes "strs" as a single string (not an array).

Comment: What error are you experiencing, if your current code does not work?

Comment: And what language are you using?

Comment: I am using C#. The problem that I have manage to solve by just assigning the whole array string into the params string[].

Comment: See the documentation for the params keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Comment: @user1918030 params is nothing but a syntactic sugar, see my explanation

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Blachshma, casperOne..reopen.

Comment: The issue is rather a simple missunderstanding/Faulty syntax.
You wanted to call something around:
Test(1, "a", "b", "c");

Comment: The problem, in my end, seems to be that if a function has overloads, and one of them is (object obj) and another is (params string[] args) - then the compiler won't choose the correct (params string[] args)

Answer (score 42):

*Actually*, the `params` is just a syntactic sugar handled by the C# compiler, so that

this:

```
void Method(params string[] args) { /**/ }
Method("one", "two", "three");
```

becomes this:

```
void Method(params string[] args) { /**/ }
Method(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" })
```

Answer (score 15):

I tested this and it works:

```
    private void CallTestMethod()
    {
        string [] strings = new string [] {"1", "2", "3"};
        Test(1, strings);

    }

    private void Test(int id, params string[] test)
    {
        //Do some action with input
    }
```

You can call it just like this `Test(1, <Some string[]>);`

**Edit**

From [MSDN website on params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a
>   variable number of arguments. You can send a comma-separated list of
>   arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration, or an
>   array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no
>   arguments. No additional parameters are permitted after the params
>   keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is
>   permitted in a method declaration.

So you could also call the `Test` method like this  `Test(1);` without compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.

```
var myStringArray = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
Test(myStringArray)
```